# Selecting max key in the reducer function

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My understanding about the reducer is that it processes one key, value pair from the intermediate o/p file of sort and shuffle. I don't know how to access that intermediate file which has the sorted & shuffled key value pairs. Once I cannot access the intermediate file, I cannot write code in the reducer module to select the largest key. I have no clue as how to program the reducer which receives one K,V pair at a time to print only the largest key and its corresponding values to the final output file.

Suppose if this is the intermediate file from the mapper which has also undergone sort and shuffling ..

1 a

2 be to

4 this what

I would want the reducer to print only "4 this what" in the final output file. Since the reducer does not have the entire file in its memory. Its not possible to write this logic in the reducer. I am wondering if there is any API support to pick the last line from the intermediate file which would eventually have the max key (keys would be sorted by default)

OR

Do I have to OVERIDE the default sort comparator to do what I want to achieve ???

Answer (score 1):

You can set a different comparator for sorting in your job:

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(LongWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);
```

This for example will sort decreasingly by a `LongWritable` key.

Comment: I can probably do that so the intermediate data file reaching the reducer would have the largest key appearing FIRST in the file. In which case, I can avoid the reducer. However I am wondering if there is a way I can override the record writer to just fetch the first line from the intermediate file (sorted in descending order) so that my final o/p file would have the largest key and its associated list of values.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have one Reducer (so all key-value pairs go to it), and have it keep track of the greatest key.

```
IntWritable currentMax = new IntWritable(-1);

public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
  if (key.compareTo(currentMax) > 0) {
    currentMax.set(key.get());
    // copy 'values' somewhere
  }
}

public void cleanup(Context context) {
  Text outputValue = //create output from saved max values;
  context.emit(currentMax, outputValue);
}
```

An additional optimization would be to either only emit the maximum key in the same way from the Mapper, or use this Reducer implementation as your Combiner class.

Comment: That's tricky and not using the power of bigdata.

Comment: @ Matt D : Thanks. It worked. I am a novice in map-reduce programming and was not completely aware of the setup and cleanup functions.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach thanks to [Thomas Jungblut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540873/thomas-jungblut).

For your driver:

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(IntWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);
```

For your reducer:

```
boolean biggestKeyDone = false;

public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
    if (!biggestKeyDone){
        // write or whatever with the values of the biggest key
        biggestKeyDone = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to write the values of the biggest key in your reducer, I suggest saving in the configuration the biggest key detected in your mapper. Like this:

```
Integer currentMax = null;

public void map(IntWritable key, Text value, Context){
    if (currentMax == null){
        currentMax = key.intValue();
    }else{
        currentMax = Math.max(currentMax.intValue(), key.get());
    }
    context.write(key, value);
}

protected void cleanup(){
    if (currentMax!=null){
        context.getConfiguration().set("biggestKey", currentMax.toString());
    }
}
```

Then, in your reducer:

```
int biggestKey = -1;
protected void setup(Context context){
    biggestKey = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("biggestKey"));
}

public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
  if (biggestKey == key.get()) {
    // write or whatever with the values of the biggest key
  }
}
```

This way you avoid wasting memory and time copying values.

Comment: The configuration is an immutable XML file on HDFS. You can't share data between mappers and reducers that way.

Comment: @ Turbero : I am not programming my mapper to detect the largest key in my problem. The mapper would be doing something else.